# How to edit a Sharepoint Control

Tags: custom-control

I am building a masterpage for a new sharepoint branding project, and I'd like to edit the content of the output contentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle". Right now it is outputting the sitename + pagename, however I would just like the page displayed. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

What you put inside the placeholder will be displayed on all pages, unless you override the content of the placeholder in the pagelayout.

Use same placeholder (ID and Name should be same) in page layout where you want to override it